# Get id of new and old content from jquery.ui.accordion

Tags: jquery, accordion

I want to launch an ajax call whenever an accordion tab is opened to get the content of that tab. For that I need to know what tab was left and what tab is opened.
From the jquery documentation:

```
$('.ui-accordion').bind('accordionchange', function(event, ui) {
  ui.newHeader // jQuery object, activated header
  ui.oldHeader // jQuery object, previous header
  ui.newContent // jQuery object, activated content
  ui.oldContent // jQuery object, previous content
});
```

In firebug I can see that what I need is the ui.newContent or ui.oldContent.
These appear to be the actually divs, so I somehow need to get at their id's.

```
function OnAccordionChanged(event, ui) {
    //get the id of the old tab
    var oldId = ui.oldContent.id;

    //apply (business) filters 
    //get the id of the new tab
    //fetch the content 
    //append to new tab
    //party
}
```

It's basically the verry first step where I fail :S

Answer (score 1):

There seems to actually be a bug or something  `newContent` will give you 'undefined' however `newHeader` will give you the

`$(ui.newHeader).attr('id')`  will give the id of the h3 tag
`$(ui.newContent).attr('id')` should give the id of the div, but does not. Instead it gives 'undefined'  even just `ui.newContent.attr('id')` which should be ok stil gives undefined.  Using the DOM tab in firebug i was able to determine a weird-improper work around

```
ui.newContent.prevObject.attr('id')
```

It seems that the div is actually in `ui.newContent.prevObject` which is a jQuery object... Seems to work flawlessly

Answer (score 0):

You get the ID of a (jQuery) DOM object via

```
my_object.attr("id")
```